# Location of Tcl 8.6 library and Location of Tk 8.6 library: not found

Tags: software-installation, tcl

Command was

```
sudo auto-apt run ./configure
```

Error message:

```
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
    Location of "tcl.h": /usr/include/tcl8.6
    Location of "tk.h": /usr/include/tcl8.6
    Location of Tcl 8.6 library: not found
    Location of Tk 8.6 library: not found
    Location of X11 library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    Checking if your system already has zlib installed: yes.

Not all settings could be determined! See above for details.

The default Makefile was written.
You will need to edit it before you can compile Scid.
```

I also can't find the libraries.
How do I overcome this?

Comment: Searching for [`tcl.h`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=tcl.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) shows the package is `tcl8.6-dev`, and correspondingly,[`tk8.6-dev` for `tk.h`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=tk.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any).

Comment: Thanks muru, but it isn't clear to me whether or not this answers my question, or I am just obtuse.

Comment: but those packages are installed? And those files were found according to the messages, the other two files were not.

Comment: I'm telling you that tc18.6-dev and tk18.6-dev are both installed. Both tcl.h and tk.h were found as I read the messages I posted. the query lines are Location of Tcl 8.6 library: not found
    Location of Tk 8.6 library: not found.

Comment: What is the software that you're compiling here?

Comment: It is the scid_vs_pc-4.9 software downloaded from sourceforge as scid_vs_pc-4.9.tgz

Comment: Then I cannot reproduce your error. I installed `tk8.6-dev`, `tcl8.6-dev`, and my output is this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23857026/

Comment: Well, I'll have another go.  Thank you very much for the trouble you have taken. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by using the latest package scid_vs_pc-4.17 instead of scid_vs_pc-4.9